# Anyone use a bare metal backup solution with ubuntu?

Tags: backup

Long time *Nix user here and now that I am retired I am searching for a complete system backup solution for my home desktop system.  I have considered dd and clonezilla but I would prefer a solution that I could schedule (with cron) that provides deduplication and compression to an NFS drive?
Of course there are several commercial versions but remember, I am retired and now poor.
Any suggestions greatly appreciated.  In the mean time I'll keep searching.
Thx :-)

Comment: Re your mention of `dd`, you might find this interesting: [dd vs cat -- is dd still relevant these days?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/12532)

Comment: dd/Clonezilla aren't very suitable for backup, they are rather for producing a complete "clone" of your system disk/partition. For regular backup, I would rather write a shell script that just copies files to the NAS. You can schedule it via cron or anacron. Deduplication could be a bit tricky, but by using rsync, you can copy only files that actually changed vs backup, and you can save the previous versions of to-be-overwritten backup files in separate directories. No need for de-dup then. I wrote such a script, but working in other direction - backup files from my VPS to home computer.

Answer (score 3):

I have used two options.

1. [rsnapshot](https://rsnapshot.org/): Can be scheduled, and does delta backups, so it's not backing up every file every time, only what's changed. Uses hard-links on the backup target to de-duplicate files. Can keep an hourly/daily/weekly/monthly hierarchy.
2. [Borg](https://www.borgbackup.org/): Very similar to, but more performant than rsnapshot.

I wrote a blog post about [Straightforward Linux Backups with rsnapshot](https://popey.com/blog/2020/12/straightforward-linux-backups-with-rsnapshot/). Then we discussed it on [Linux Matters](https://linuxmatters.sh) [Episode 9: "Big Backup Bonanza"](https://linuxmatters.sh/9/) (there's an ai-generated transcript on the page if you prefer not to listen).

I found both to be excellent. Now I have switched to Borg, I won't go back. From what you've said, I think Borg could work for you.

Comment: Thanks popey.  I will give Borg a try.

Answer (score 1):

On thousands of server at work we use [Relax-and-recover](https://relax-and-recover.org/) for bare metal backup.

REAR can then mount & store the data on an NFS drive if that is what you want.

Integration with many backup software like [Borg](https://www.borgbackup.org/) is also supported.

Comment: Interestingly enough ReaR claims it does exactly what I am looking for.  But honestly I have spent time over the past year trying to get ReaR working and I cannot.  I can init the repository but for what ever reason the backup function doesn't run.  It just sits there not doing anything with no messages/error.  I can to manually cancel the job to regain control.  Any thought as to what I should/could look at?

Comment: RarR creates a verbose log file under /var/log/rear/, start from here